# Security Exception: Permission Denial

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

The app used to run. However, just recently it began to stop working. The device is running Android Nutella. Below is the LogCat.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.music.store.ConfigContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.music.ConfigContent/one-key/2/ExplicitRestrictedByParentControl from pid=2500, uid=10373 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

The app crashes in the the following code snippet on the last line(contained in a SongParser method).

```
 String[] projection2 = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
    Uri songUri=null;
    try {
        songUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio");
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (songUri!=null) {
        CursorLoader cl2 = new CursorLoader(context,
                songUri, projection2, null, null, null);
        cursor = cl2.loadInBackground();
```

I grant the Uri permissions in the following method after asking for permissions through the runtime permissions methods.

```
 private void startService() {
    //start intent to RssService for feedback
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SongService.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    getContext().grantUriPermission("xxx.xxx.xxx.SongService",Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio"),Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra(SongService.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
    getActivity().startService(intent);

}
```

Here is where SongService calls SongParser.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        List<String> eventItems= null;
    if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
        parser = new SongParser();
        eventItems = parser.getAllArtists(getApplicationContext());
    }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ITEMS, (Serializable) eventItems);
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RECEIVER);
        receiver.send(0, bundle);}}
```

I have contained the permissions in the manifest as well. Again, this exception seemingly happened on its own.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue when using the Google Play Music ContentProvider. It's working fine on my phone but it seems to be crashing for some users. I have Play Music version 7.6.4620-1.P.3889101, what about you?

Comment: Yes, same version as that

Comment: I pushed an update to my app that catches the SecurityException and ignores it. Someone emailed me to tell me it's fixed. I'm not sure what's going on but hey, problem solved apparently.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that for some reason, the (exported) MusicContent provider will redirect to ConfigContentProvider, which is **not** exported.

It seems that the way to solve it is to open Google Play Music. If you haven't launched it in a while, it will redirect to com.google.android.music.store.ConfigContentProvider and trigger a SecurityException. It's kind of problematic but at least I can tell my users what to do. Let me know if you can come up with something better.

It might also be a good idea to file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have access to that `ContentProvider`. It is not exported, and that app did not pass you a `Uri` that you can use to access it.

Since presumably the `Uri` is from an app that you did not write, apparently an update to that app changed this behavior.